# Excel Put forward slash after number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can anybody help with excel function, Im trying to add a forward slash after number:

```
Before: 10293Test / Test Demo
After : 10293 / Test / Test Demo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you have a try following formula and feedback your response.

```
=LOOKUP(10^15,--LEFT(A1,ROW($1:$15))) & " / " & TRIM(MID(A1,LEN(LOOKUP(10^15,--LEFT(A1,ROW($1:$15))))+1,100))
```

Comment: @user10782905 If it works then you should accept (tick as green) my answer so that other user can know it helped you.

Comment: i just green ticked it

Answer (score 1):

```
=concat(left(A1,5)," / ", mid(A1,6,len(A1)))
```

Replace A1 with the cell where you have the text

Comment: Thanks this works but some cells have numbers length of 3 or 4 the number varies.I see you used 5 digits. Can you provide a function for that?

Comment: @Ricardo You should consider first numeric characters length may be different in case of real data. So, it is not good way to make static left 5 character.

Comment: @Harun24HR do you have better solution that might help for my situation?

Comment: @user10782905 Have a try my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
 =CONCAT(LEFT(A1,MATCH(1,ISERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)))*1,0)-1), " / ", MID(A1,MATCH(1,ISERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)))*1,0),LEN(A1)))
```

This builds from Ricardo's solution above, and from this answer here: https://discuss.analyticsvidhya.com/t/how-to-find-first-non-numeric-character-in-the-string-using-excel/331/2

Note that the formula from that link is used twice in the function to get the position of the last number. You must use ctrl-shift-enter every time you edit the formula for it to work (it's an array-type formula).